# How to prevent user from entering data more than once(NSDate)

Tags: ios6, nsdate

I would like to ask for suggestion about the following matter: let's say i have an app where the user enters data each day in an iphone(data stored with core data) and I would to prevent the user from adding data more than once for a same, how could that be done in the viewcontroller?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the UI, that lets the user enter data after it has been done already for the day. Other than that, it totally depends on your code and logic of the app. It is up to you as the engineer/programmer to implement a way so that the data cannot be changed more than once.

Good luck!